# Respuesta diferente en api rest

Tags: php

Como estan? Soy nuevo en php y desarrollo web. Estoy con una apirest con slim framework . En mi equipo con xampp  funciona como lo programe pero en el hosting la respuesta es otra siendo el codigo el mismo. Miren.. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola gadoves, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Completa el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio en general (y ganar tu primera medalla). También lee [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus preguntas, por ejemplo: para ilustrar un problema, no sólo incluyas imágenes, son más difíciles de leer y no se indexa su contenido (por lo que no se pueden buscar), trata de poner texto: ¿cómo es la petición? (sin incluir parámetros sensibles como claves) y ¿cuál es el resultado que obtienes en cada caso?

Comment: ay! mis pobres y chicatos ojos xD